# Cant increase memory heap space for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, crash, ide

I've been trying to increase the heap space for my Eclipse IDE for a while now, I've read that all I have to do is increase the -Xmx option in my eclipse.ini file, but it has not worked, if I try and change the -Xms option, Eclipse wont even launch, I have been unable to increase it over 256m which is the default value. It is annoying since everytime i launch eclipse it runs out of memory, I am fairly new at programming and computer stuff, so i wanted to ask for assistance, thank you for reading my question!

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\Dioni\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.100.v20210209-1541
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
C:\Users\Dioni\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.19.0.20210311-1200
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

[image: This is the heap status shown in Eclipse]

**System properties: **

```
applicationXMI=org.eclipse.ui.workbench/LegacyIDE.e4xmi
ds.delayed.keepInstances=true
ds.delayed.keepInstances.default=true
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.buildId=4.19.0.I20210303-1800
eclipse.commands=-os
win32
-ws
win32
-arch
x86_64
-showsplash
C:\Users\Dioni\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.19.0.20210311-1200\splash.bmp
-launcher
C:\Users\Dioni\eclipse\java-2021-03\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name
Eclipse
--launcher.library
C:\Users\Dioni\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.100.v20210209-1541\eclipse_11301.dll
-startup
C:\Users\Dioni\eclipse\java-2021-03\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-clean
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin\server\jvm.dll
eclipse.home.location=file:/C:/Users/Dioni/eclipse/java-2021-03/eclipse/
eclipse.launcher=C:\Users\Dioni\eclipse\java-2021-03\eclipse\eclipse.exe
eclipse.launcher.name=Eclipse
eclipse.p2.data.area=file:/C:/Users/Dioni/.p2/
eclipse.p2.max.threads=10
eclipse.p2.profile=C__Users_Dioni_eclipse_java-2021-03_eclipse
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
eclipse.startTime=1622921710439
eclipse.stateSaveDelayInterval=30000
eclipse.vm=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin\server\jvm.dll
eclipse.vmargs=-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-Djava.class.path=C:\Users\Dioni\eclipse\java-2021-03\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar
equinox.init.uuid=true
file.encoding=Cp1252
file.separator=\
gosh.args=--nointeractive
java.class.path=C:\Users\Dioni\eclipse\java-2021-03\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar
java.class.version=60.0
java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1
java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Dioni\AppData\Local\Temp\
java.library.path=C:\Users\Dioni\eclipse\java-2021-03\eclipse;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Dioni\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;;.
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version=16.0.1+9-24
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version=16
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=https://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug=https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/
java.version=16.0.1
java.version.date=2021-04-20
java.vm.compressedOopsMode=32-bit
java.vm.info=mixed mode, sharing
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version=16
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version=16.0.1+9-24
jdk.debug=release
line.separator=

oomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
oomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
org.eclipse.debug.ui.breakpoints.toggleFactoriesUsed=false
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.splash.location=C:\Users\Dioni\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.19.0.20210311-1200\splash.bmp
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
org.eclipse.m2e.log.dir=C:\Users\Dioni\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration
org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
org.eclipse.swt.internal.deviceZoom=100
org.osgi.framework.executionenvironment=OSGi/Minimum-1.0, OSGi/Minimum-1.1, OSGi/Minimum-1.2, JavaSE/compact1-1.8, JavaSE/compact2-1.8, JavaSE/compact3-1.8, JRE-1.1, J2SE-1.2, J2SE-1.3, J2SE-1.4, J2SE-1.5, JavaSE-1.6, JavaSE-1.7, JavaSE-1.8, JavaSE-9, JavaSE-10, JavaSE-11, JavaSE-12, JavaSE-13, JavaSE-14, JavaSE-15, JavaSE-16
org.osgi.framework.language=en
org.osgi.framework.os.name=Windows10
org.osgi.framework.os.version=10.0.0
org.osgi.framework.processor=x86-64
org.osgi.framework.storage=C:\Users\Dioni\eclipse\java-2021-03\eclipse\configuration
org.osgi.framework.system.capabilities=osgi.ee; osgi.ee="OSGi/Minimum"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1, 1.2", osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JRE"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1", osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE/compact1"; version:List<Version>="1.8, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE/compact2"; version:List<Version>="1.8, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE/compact3"; version:List<Version>="1.8, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0"
org.osgi.framework.system.packages=com.sun.jarsigner, com.sun.java.accessibility.util, com.sun.jdi, com.sun.jdi.connect, com.sun.jdi.connect.spi, com.sun.jdi.event, com.sun.jdi.request, com.sun.management, com.sun.net.httpserver, com.sun.net.httpserver.spi, com.sun.nio.file, com.sun.nio.sctp, com.sun.security.auth, com.sun.security.auth.callback, com.sun.security.auth.login, com.sun.security.auth.module, com.sun.security.jgss, com.sun.source.doctree, com.sun.source.tree, com.sun.source.util, com.sun.tools.attach, com.sun.tools.attach.spi, com.sun.tools.javac, com.sun.tools.jconsole, java.applet, java.awt, java.awt.color, java.awt.datatransfer, java.awt.desktop, java.awt.dnd, java.awt.event, java.awt.font, java.awt.geom, java.awt.im, java.awt.im.spi, java.awt.image, java.awt.image.renderable, java.awt.print, java.beans, java.beans.beancontext, java.io, java.lang, java.lang.annotation, java.lang.constant, java.lang.instrument, java.lang.invoke, java.lang.management, java.lang.module, java.lang.ref, java.lang.reflect, java.lang.runtime, java.math, java.net, java.net.http, java.net.spi, java.nio, java.nio.channels, java.nio.channels.spi, java.nio.charset, java.nio.charset.spi, java.nio.file, java.nio.file.attribute, java.nio.file.spi, java.rmi, java.rmi.activation, java.rmi.dgc, java.rmi.registry, java.rmi.server, java.security, java.security.cert, java.security.interfaces, java.security.spec, java.sql, java.text, java.text.spi, java.time, java.time.chrono, java.time.format, java.time.temporal, java.time.zone, java.util, java.util.concurrent, java.util.concurrent.atomic, java.util.concurrent.locks, java.util.function, java.util.jar, java.util.logging, java.util.prefs, java.util.regex, java.util.spi, java.util.stream, java.util.zip, javax.accessibility, javax.annotation.processing, javax.crypto, javax.crypto.interfaces, javax.crypto.spec, javax.imageio, javax.imageio.event, javax.imageio.metadata, javax.imageio.plugins.bmp, javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg, javax.imageio.plugins.tiff, javax.imageio.spi, javax.imageio.stream, javax.lang.model, javax.lang.model.element, javax.lang.model.type, javax.lang.model.util, javax.management, javax.management.loading, javax.management.modelmbean, javax.management.monitor, javax.management.openmbean, javax.management.relation, javax.management.remote, javax.management.remote.rmi, javax.management.timer, javax.naming, javax.naming.directory, javax.naming.event, javax.naming.ldap, javax.naming.ldap.spi, javax.naming.spi, javax.net, javax.net.ssl, javax.print, javax.print.attribute, javax.print.attribute.standard, javax.print.event, javax.rmi.ssl, javax.script, javax.security.auth, javax.security.auth.callback, javax.security.auth.kerberos, javax.security.auth.login, javax.security.auth.spi, javax.security.auth.x500, javax.security.cert, javax.security.sasl, javax.smartcardio, javax.sound.midi, javax.sound.midi.spi, javax.sound.sampled, javax.sound.sampled.spi, javax.sql, javax.sql.rowset, javax.sql.rowset.serial, javax.sql.rowset.spi, javax.swing, javax.swing.border, javax.swing.colorchooser, javax.swing.event, javax.swing.filechooser, javax.swing.plaf, javax.swing.plaf.basic, javax.swing.plaf.metal, javax.swing.plaf.multi, javax.swing.plaf.nimbus, javax.swing.plaf.synth, javax.swing.table, javax.swing.text, javax.swing.text.html, javax.swing.text.html.parser, javax.swing.text.rtf, javax.swing.tree, javax.swing.undo, javax.tools, javax.transaction.xa, javax.xml, javax.xml.catalog, javax.xml.crypto, javax.xml.crypto.dom, javax.xml.crypto.dsig, javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom, javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo, javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec, javax.xml.datatype, javax.xml.namespace, javax.xml.parsers, javax.xml.stream, javax.xml.stream.events, javax.xml.stream.util, javax.xml.transform, javax.xml.transform.dom, javax.xml.transform.sax, javax.xml.transform.stax, javax.xml.transform.stream, javax.xml.validation, javax.xml.xpath, jdk.dynalink, jdk.dynalink.beans, jdk.dynalink.linker, jdk.dynalink.linker.support, jdk.dynalink.support, jdk.incubator.foreign, jdk.incubator.vector, jdk.javadoc.doclet, jdk.jfr, jdk.jfr.consumer, jdk.jshell, jdk.jshell.execution, jdk.jshell.spi, jdk.jshell.tool, jdk.management.jfr, jdk.net, jdk.nio, jdk.nio.mapmode, jdk.security.jarsigner, jdk.swing.interop, netscape.javascript, org.ietf.jgss, org.w3c.dom, org.w3c.dom.bootstrap, org.w3c.dom.css, org.w3c.dom.events, org.w3c.dom.html, org.w3c.dom.ls, org.w3c.dom.ranges, org.w3c.dom.stylesheets, org.w3c.dom.traversal, org.w3c.dom.views, org.w3c.dom.xpath, org.xml.sax, org.xml.sax.ext, org.xml.sax.helpers, sun.misc, sun.reflect
org.osgi.framework.uuid=424bd4ca-d264-4fd5-915f-5a087298425e
org.osgi.framework.vendor=Eclipse
org.osgi.framework.version=1.10.0
org.osgi.supports.framework.extension=true
org.osgi.supports.framework.fragment=true
org.osgi.supports.framework.requirebundle=true
os.arch=amd64
os.name=Windows 10
os.version=10.0
osgi.arch=x86_64
osgi.bundles=reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.2.300.v20210212-1137.jar,reference:file:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.3.600.v20200721-1308.jar@1:start
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
osgi.clean=true
osgi.compatibility.bootdelegation=true
osgi.compatibility.bootdelegation.default=true
osgi.configuration.area=file:/C:/Users/Dioni/eclipse/java-2021-03/eclipse/configuration/
osgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
osgi.framework=file:/C:/Users/Dioni/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.16.200.v20210226-1447.jar
osgi.framework.extensions=reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.2.300.v20210212-1137.jar
osgi.framework.shape=jar
osgi.framework.useSystemProperties=true
osgi.frameworkClassPath=., file:C:/Users/Dioni/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.2.300.v20210212-1137.jar
osgi.install.area=file:/C:/Users/Dioni/eclipse/java-2021-03/eclipse/
osgi.instance.area=file:/C:/Users/Dioni/eclipse-workspace/
osgi.instance.area.default=file:/C:/Users/Dioni/eclipse-workspace/
osgi.logfile=C:\Users\Dioni\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.log
osgi.nl=en_US
osgi.os=win32
osgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
osgi.splashLocation=C:\Users\Dioni\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.19.0.20210311-1200\splash.bmp
osgi.splashPath=file:/C:/Users/Dioni/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.19.0.v20210303-1800
osgi.syspath=c:\Users\Dioni\.p2\pool\plugins
osgi.tracefile=C:\Users\Dioni\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\trace.log
osgi.ws=win32
path.separator=;
sun.arch.data.model=64
sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.cpu.isalist=amd64
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
sun.java.command=Eclipse
sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
sun.os.patch.level=
user.country=US
user.dir=C:\WINDOWS\system32
user.home=C:\Users\Dioni
user.language=en
user.name=Dioni
user.script=
user.timezone=Europe/Budapest
user.variant=
```

Comment: Paste you eclipse.ini here and mark those changes that do not work.

Comment: -vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m

the changes that dont work is when i change -Xms256m to Xms 1024 or another value

the -Xmx value is 2048 but yet the max memory allocated to Eclipse is still only 256m

Comment: First, before increasing the memory, make sure your Eclipse is up to date and it is not caused by a plugin you have installed. I would also recommend to use the in Eclipse embedded Java. Second, to increase the memory, you have to increase `-Xmx`, not `-Xms`. Please edit your question and add the whole `eclipse.ini` formatted as code snippet.

Comment: I updated it and added the entire file, the problem is no matter how much i increase my -Xmx option, the max heap space is still only 256m, ill add a screenshot to understand better

Comment: @DionOsmani have you tried launching with -clean option - in the past when things stopped working -clean seemed to help.

Comment: @MrR Tried it a while back, just tried it again to make sure, it had no effect unfortunately

Comment: Are you sure that is the eclipse.ini that is actually being used? It should be the in the same directory as the eclipse.exe you are running.

Comment: Yes, i am definitely sure im using the right eclipse.ini file

Comment: Install visualvm: https://visualvm.github.io/ . Select the Eclipse process and check the "Java Home" and other clues. That might help.

Comment: This is what VisualVM shows me:
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, sharing)
Java: version 16.0.1, vendor Oracle Corporation
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1
JVM Flags: <none>

Comment: In your question, there is no contradiction to the `eclipse.ini` and what the screenshot shows. Please show also the changed `eclipse.ini`. In _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_, tab _Configuration_ in the `*** System properties:` section you can see the used VM and VM arguments.

Comment: Just edited the question and added what you asked for, i see nothing that I can change there? sorry for my inexperience as i am fairly new to this

Comment: @DionOsmani In your `eclipse.ini` you have a minimum of 256M and a maximum of 2048M. According to the installation details, these settings are indeed used. The heap status shows that 209M is currently required, which is less than the minimum, and therefore no more memory needs to be allocated. So everything works as expected.

Comment: @howlger The `max: 256M` in the heap status screen shot looks wrong. This comes from `Runtime.maxMemory`, on my system it says 2048m

Comment: @greg-449 Ah, now I understand. Thanks for the hint. I can not reproduce it either with Eclipse 2021-03 and with the JustJ Java 16.0.1 HotSpot VM (on my system it says also `max: 2048M`). Maybe it is caused by a broken/modified Java installation.

Comment: @howlger I downloaded the JDK from oracle and made sure its the right one, i tested out with eclipse recently and found out that i can decrease the Xms, but still the max Ram usage is 256, so its not that the file is not working, rather thats the max Ram my computer can allocate? I dont understand why that would be the problem when my pc has 16 GB of RAM, do any of u know why that would be?

Comment: @DionOsmani I cannot reproduce this. What do you get when installing the latest Java provided by Eclipse JustJ as plugin: _Help > Install New Software..._, work with [`https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/latest`](https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/latest) and choosing _JustJ OpenJDK Hotspot JRE **Complete**_?

Comment: @howlger just installed it, but now eclipse crashes on every launch, i cant look at anything

Comment: oh... and i just saw with task manager, whenever i launch eclipse CPU usage goes up to 100% for a few seconds

Comment: Maybe this is caused by a plugin you have installed. For example, all Genuιtec plugins patches Eclipse at runtime via load time weaving to try to cheat the open source license, and this slows down Eclipse and might cause issue. So try a fresh Eclipse installation.

Comment: @howlger ive tried both a Eclipse and JDK re installation, it still didnt seem to help